# Android - refresh app after changing settings

Tags: android, refresh

In my app I have an "option" menu in which the user can change some preferences.
How can I refresh the app after changing those settings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those preferences are stored in SharedPreferences, why don't you implement  [SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html)

Comment: this is pretty slick. However, some changes can't be done dynamically. For instance, grid view item sizes can't. In this case, you just need to restart the app.

Comment: i've my preferences saved on a txt file created in the sd card, and when the app start it reads them from this file. there's no way to restart my app programmatically?

Comment: Why don't you use the tools Android give us? I think it's a waste of time a resources to create your own system to store simple data.